# Getting x,y positions of networkx draw_network object

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I need to generate synthetic network samples for a latent space model, instead of doing it by hand I figured I could use the networkX plot tool to generate the samples for me.

```
import networkx as nx
a = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10,2)
nx.draw_networkx(a,with_labels=True,node_size=300)
```

[image]

The positions of the nodes returned in an numpy array is exactly what I am looking for, are there any easy way to achieve this?

e.g [(-0.24,-0.22),(-0.15,0.1),...,)] for point 1,2,...,n

Comment: `draw_networkx` uses spring_layout by default to calculate positions. To get them you explicitly call: `positions = nx.spring_layout(graph)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default drawing uses the positions calculated by `spring_layout`.  You should be aware that each call to `spring_layout` uses a random seed to choose the initial positions of the nodes.  So the output each time is random.

The best way to handle this is to set the positions in advance with a call to `nx.spring_layout` and then pass those positions in the optional `pos` keyword argument to the drawing command (this also helps when you don't want to draw all of the graph at once, and you don't want to deal with the node positions changing in future drawings).

```
import networkx as nx
a = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10,2)
pos = nx.spring_layout(a)
nx.draw_networkx(a, pos = pos, with_labels=True,node_size=300)
```